# Dovecot doesn't listen on 993(imaps)

Tags: dovecot

I opend only port 993(imaps) for imap server but dovecot opens port 143.
my setting for dovecost in dovecot -n is following

```
sudo dovecot -n
# 2.2.18: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.8 (0c4ae064f307+)
# OS: Linux 4.2.0-24-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 15.10
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

But netstat only indicating port 143 opens

```
sudo netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15556/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1922/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1156/x11vnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16566/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1381/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      746/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      660/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15556/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1922/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1134/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      15556/master
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1922/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      1156/x11vnc
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      16566/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1809/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      746/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      660/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      15556/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1809/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1922/smbd
```

Actually, I don't use iptable and ufw neither.

Do you anyone know about this matter and help solve this issue?
It's happend from upgrade ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 yesterday.

Comment: Do you really need to use port 993? It's somewhat obsolete now, the modern way is to use port 143 with STARTTLS. See http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks for the comment
I also want to avoid obsolete style. I will find out port 143 use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SHOULD add `imaps` to the list of `protocols` in the `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` to enable port 993.

```
protocols = imap imaps
```

Comment: Dear Kondybas, 
Thanks for the answer

But, you know adding protocols "imaps" isn't supported.
dovecot -n said it's syntax error. Maybe imaps will not be supported any longer?

Comment: Option `imaps` is now obsolete.